# jQuery - draggable div with shadow - problem in Opera

Tags: jquery, draggable, opera, shadow

I have a problem in Opera 11.50 @ Windows 7.

This is my code and [live preview](http://jsbin.com/afepew):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #draggable { 
      width: 100px;
      height: 70px;
      background: silver;
      box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="draggable">Drag me</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I drag div around, it leaves "traces" of shadow. Especially if I drag it fast in upper direction. In Chrome and Firefox it works and looks good.

Anybody have idea or suggestion?

Thanks!

Edit: [Here](http://i53.tinypic.com/2i7bmut.png) is a screenshot too.

Comment: Not seeing a problem on your sample, or on jsfiddle (11.50 on mac): http://jsfiddle.net/EVhRz/ -- maybe it's the difference in Opera versions for different OS?

Comment: Thanks for replay. It's not problem of jsbin or jsfiddle (i got same results even in jsfiddle). This is just a demo. [Here](http://i53.tinypic.com/2i7bmut.png) is a screenshot of how it looks. But it's good to know that on mac it works good :)

Comment: I can confirm this too on OS X Lion/Opera 11.50. But I think, that this is problem of the Opera's rendering engine.

Comment: The best result if you drag from the bottom to top: [img](https://img.skitch.com/20110906-egdrsybx8qif2bx1jukj5e186j.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
#draggable {
  display:inline-block;

}
```

to the css style. This worked for me on opera 11.6

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a rendering engine bug that has been fixed for Opera 12 (works for me in O12 builds, WinXP).

Comment: Thanks, but Opera12 was released recently... I dough that all Opera users were updated. I'm still looking for some adequate solution.

Comment: Opera 12 is still in beta, sorry about that. However, any workaround you are likely to find for an issue like this is going to be a hack. You could try to force repaint of the document by setting document.body.className or something like that. If you try such workarounds, I'd actually use some browser sniffing to limit the workarounds to only browsers/versions with the known problem you're handling.